# User script input in java

Tags: java, function, input, scripting

I am developing a java app where the user inputs certain functions through a property files. The functions are then evaluated at runtime with variable values provided by the app.

Here a simple example. The user wants to calculate the return on investment for a certain capital allocation over the next n years. He should be able to input not just relevant parameters, but a function that calculates the return year by year.

Can anyone suggest or recommend a scripting language which is simple , so that the user learning curve is not too steep, and for which a standard library providing integration with java code is available?

A related example would be welcome too.

Comment: Thanks for every answer. Stackoverflow never fails to deliver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My suggestion is to use `ScriptEngine` and evaluate `Javascript` functions. As simple as:

```
public class TestScriptEngine {

    private static final String script = "var customFunction = function(parameter) {\n" +
            "\treturn parameter*parameter;\n" +
            "};\n" +
            "\n" +
            "println(customFunction(10));\n";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ScriptEngineManager factory = new ScriptEngineManager();
        ScriptEngine engine = factory.getEngineByName("JavaScript");
        // evaluate JavaScript code User's input
        try {
            engine.eval(script);
        } catch (ScriptException e) {
            e.printStackTrace(); 
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using javascript. It is simple enough and the Rhino library is integrated with java. Complete information can be found here: [Rhino](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/scripting/programmer_guide/index.html)

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look at Groovy. It can be embedded in Java applications and be a useful tool for scripting in applications.

http://groovy.codehaus.org/Embedding+Groovy

Answer (score 0):

You could use JavaScript or Ruby, they should be convenient enough.